# SQL Server CLR Trigger with SMO or Linq?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, triggers, smo

I've been looking at the possibility of creating a CLR trigger for insert, but every tutorial found gives me examples of using ado.net objects to do the logic - this is not very convenient way..(I don't think I have to convince anyone about that)

I was wondering if maybe there is another way for doing this? SMO? Linq? Anything except plain ADO.NET ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server only supports a small subset of CLR assemblies [Supported .NET Framework Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx):

- CustomMarshalers
- Microsoft.VisualBasic
- Microsoft.VisualC
- mscorlib
- System
- System.Configuration
- System.Data
- System.Data.OracleClient
- System.Data.SqlXml
- System.Deployment
- System.Security
- System.Transactions
- System.Web.Services
- System.Xml
- System.Core.dll
- System.Xml.Linq.dll

LINQ is supported, but LINQ.Data is not, so you can use linq over objects not linq 2 sql.